# Where can I find an explanation of all the options in the dx tool

Tags: android, dx

Where can I find an explanation of all the options in the dx tool if you type dx --help you only get an explanation for some of the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [dx source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/345ff1a1cbfd623d805b385ff92265b537821ccd/dx/src/com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main.java#1235) for more information.